# grep multiple directories throws error "Is a directory"

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have to read time taken for each operation as highlighted by JR_*, time is in t="" from the latest 10 jtl files, and compute the average value. I am trying to do a shell script which will do this specific action of computing average of a particular operation for the last 10 runs, (read latest 10 jtl files)

```
<sample t="5203" it="0" lt="0" ts="1493818151051" s="true" lb="JR_READ" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="0" ng="2" na="2"/>
<sample t="3584" it="0" lt="0" ts="1493818151660" s="true" lb="JR_WRITE" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="0" ng="2" na="2"/>
<sample t="61280" it="0" lt="0" ts="1493818152265" s="true" lb="JR_SAVE" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="0" ng="2" na="2"/>
<sample t="129935" it="0" lt="0" ts="1493818152870" s="true" lb="JR_DELETE" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="0" ng="2" na="2"/>



 #!/bin/sh
    cd /tests/unit/
    fNames=$(ls -t | grep -i jenkins-TEST_UNIT | head -n 10)
    #printf "%s\n" "${fNames[@]}"
    ## now loop through the above array
    for i in "${fNames[@]}"
    do
       #echo "$i"
      grep -I "JR_READ" $i/Summary.jtl | awk -F '"' '{print $2}'
       # or do whatever with individual element of the array
    done
```

I get the "time" as needed for only one file, rest of the directories I get this error, what could be the reason? grep works fine ONLY for ONE file. I want to read this particular value from 10 files and compute average for it.

```
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT12: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT9: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT8: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT7: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT6: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT5: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT4: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT3: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT2: Is a directory
60665
```

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: `grep` only accepts _files_ as operands by default; you can pass _directories_ combined with `-r`, assuming you want to search their files recursively.

Comment: What do you see when you uncomment `echo "$i"`?  Or even better, `echo "_${i}_"`.